# I had no difficulty to do /doing

Tags: adjectives, sentence-structure

Although I know that the structure of

> I had no difficulty (in) doing something

is grammatically correct, would it be completely wrong to say

> I had no difficulty to do something.

Comment: I should add more 'I had no difficulty for doing something' .....May be three sentences have same meaning.

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the entry in the Cambridge Dictionary for **[difficulty](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/difficulty)**, in the section **the fact of not being easy to do or understand**, the only sanctioned ways of talking about the difficulty of an activity are **+ -ing verb** and (in the UK) **in + -ing verb**.

If you look at the entry for **[difficult](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/difficult)**, you will see that both **+ -ing verb** and **+ to infinitive** are sanctioned.

Your second sentence is therefore incorrect. A listener would understand, but would assume that you were not a native speaker.

---

I thought that maybe there might be a noun-versus-adjective rule for this as difficult is an adjective and difficulty is a noun, but **pleasure** is a noun and both **in + -ing verb** and **+ to infinitive** are sanctioned. I guess you just need to check the dictionary for the word you want to use if you are unsure.

Answer (score 1):

The second sentence is incorrect, for you cannot really say

> I had no difficulty to do something.

It doesn't make much sense, you use "had" as a past tense, and while "to do something" can be in a past tense too, in this context it simply isn't in the past tense, you could make the sentence work by saying

> I had no difficulty doing "something"

which would imply you had no issues doing a certain action while the original would mean "you had no difficulty to do a thing" which makes little sense.

Comment: That is not the reason: it is nothing to do with the tense. JavaLatte has the whole answer: it is the (arbitrary) requirement of the particular word "difficulty", which has to be learnt along with the meaning of the word.

Comment: That makes sense I guess